# Powerpoint 2007 - Inserting dynamic data

Tags: vba, fonts, label, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

so I've found that Powerpoint 2007 has no bookmark functionality. So I can't just insert dynamic data into a presentation. Also, there are no autostart event handler, but I found a way of doing it by editing the XML data. This now works, I've got a custom event handler that is run as expected.

Now, I tried to solve the no bookmark functionality by adding a label insted. Since a label has a name I can assign the Caption property a value. And that value can be dynamic data. 
And this actually works, yay! BUT, this presentation has a custom font and font embedding is crucial. And now I've found that PowerPoint 2007 doesn't look to support font embedding on labels. And probably not buttons and textboxes as well. That is, the typical visual studio controls.

Are there any other ways of fixing this? A normal text placeholder doesn't have an ID. 
But can I target them anyway? It's just some text in the footer of a slide design that I'm trying to put dynamic data.

Comment: I found a way of targeting text boxes anyway. So this doesn't really apply anymore. I found I can select the textboxes I want by targeting the ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Item(11).Select. This target textbox 11 in the selected slidemaster. Works good :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found out how to target textboxes in PowerPoint 2007.

```
ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Item(11).Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=25).Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Text = "New text that should be inserted"
```

The problem now is how to run this automatically. New thread for that.